# Injecting records using T-SQL based on intersections

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm

I hypothesize using `LAG` and `LEAD` in T-SQL can solve this riddle using one view and CTEs (SQL Server 2012). Proof required for when input values are equal, intersect, or are mutually exclusive.

The idea is to "overwrite" existing data with new data, but preserving the old data for when it does not intersect with the newer data. I've simplified the problem with easy numbers instead of my real case which contains dates and values over multiple columns.

Here is an example:

**Existing data:**

```
col1   fd   ed
----------------
 A      6    15
 A     30   100
 B      1     7
 C      2     8
```

**New data as input:**

```
A    1    7
A   16  110
C    0    4
```

**Expected output:**

```
A    1    7
A    8   15
A   16  110
B    1    7
C    0    4
C    5    8
```

**Setup:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl]
(
    [col1] [CHAR](1) NULL,
    [fd] [INT] NULL,
    [td] [INT] NULL
)
```

**Trial query:**

```
with src  as
(
select
col1 = 'A'
,fd = 1
,ed = 7 etc... 
)
-- vs 6 - 15
,
gen as
(
select 
col1 
,LAG(fd,1,fd) OVER (PARTITION BY  col1 ORDER BY fd ASC) lag_fd
,fd
,LEAD(fd,1,fd) OVER (PARTITION BY  col1 ORDER BY fd ASC) lead_fd
,LAG(td,1,td) OVER (PARTITION BY  col1 ORDER BY td ASC) lag_td
,td
,LEAD(td,1,td) OVER (PARTITION BY  col1 ORDER BY td ASC) lead_td
,ROW_NUMBER ( ) OVER (PARTITION BY col1  ORDER BY fd  ASC) rn

from
(
select * from tbl
union
select * from src 
) dat
)
SELECT
lag_fd, 
lead_fd 
FROM gen where col1 = 'A' and rn = 1 
union  
SELECT
lead_fd,
lag_td 
FROM gen where col1 = 'A' and rn = 2
union  
SELECT
lag_td,
lead_td 
FROM gen where col1 = 'A' and rn >= 2
```

Comment: where `A,1,5` came from on your expected output ?

Comment: Actually I just dont understand the logic for your output. Please explain

Comment: Given original data range 6 to 15, and input data 1 to 7, intersect the input data to the original data while keeping distinct original data in tact - so that is 1 to 7, and keep 8 to 15 which is from the original data.

Comment: Please explain the logic. We aren't mind readers.

Comment: Hope that clarifies things?

Comment: Yes. I see you have `{6, 15}` intersect with input `{1, 7}`  and generate `{1,7}` and `{8,15}` what happen if you also have `{10,20}` as input. What would be the result ?

Comment: please show expected result for input `C,1,3`

Answer (score 1):

the solution is a bit long. It breaks down to 3 sections. `rows original from tbl`, `input without intersect with tbl` and `input with intersect with tbl`

```
; with 
org_tbl as
(
    select  *, flag = 'original from tbl'
    from    tbl t
    where   not exists
            (
                select  *
                from    input i
                where   i.col1  = t.col1
                and     (
                            t.fd    between i.fd and i.td
                        or  t.td    between i.fd and i.td
                        )
            )
),
no_intersect as 
(
    select  *, flag = 'input no intersact with tbl'
    from    input i
    where   not exists
            (
                select  *
                from    tbl t
                where   i.col1  = t.col1
                and     (
                            i.fd    between t.fd and t.td
                        or  i.td    between t.fd and t.td
                        )
            )
),
intersect_work as
(
    select  i.*
    from    input i
            inner join tbl t    on  i.col1  = t.col1
                                and (   
                                        i.fd    between t.fd and t.td
                                    or  i.td    between t.fd and t.td
                                    )
        union all
        select  t.*
        from    input i
                inner join tbl t on  i.col1 = t.col1
                                 and (  
                                        i.fd    between t.fd and t.td
                                     or i.td    between t.fd and t.td
                                     )
),
with_intersect as
(

    select  i.col1,
            fd  = case  when    LAG(i.td) OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY i.fd)
                        between i.fd and i.td
                        then    LAG(i.td) OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY i.fd) + 1
                        else    i.fd    
                        end,
            td      = i.td,
            flag    = 'input intersect with tbl'
    from    intersect_work i
)
select  * from org_tbl
union all
select  * from no_intersect
union all
select  * from with_intersect
order by col1, fd
```

Comment: Great foundation, There are some cases where this breaks: (1) when the input fd and td are equal to the original. (2) a case where the input starts between and ends after the original data. Note ** the input overrides the original data **

Comment: Next time you should provide a more detailed sample data

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll be sure to.